# Find the nearest time in array with a given time using vb.net

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, time, arraylist

I can't figure it out how to do this in Vb.net since i'm new into it. I also dont know if there's already a syntax for this or maybe don't have the right logic.
Here's the situation:

I have a table for logs of members, each member can logged in or out several times per day.
Some of them are day shift and some are night shift. I already get the correct results for the minimum loginTime of that day and maximum logoutTime of that day or the next day(if graveyard). But just having this problem since data the was like this:

```
                          Table_Logs    

MembersName    LoginTime     LoginDate      LogoutTime    LogoutDate

Banog, Anna     00:26:00     2014-02-11     01:00:00       2014-02-11
Banog, Anna     12:49:00     2014-02-11     12:49:00       2014-02-11
Banog, Anna     13:16:00     2014-02-11     01:01:00       2014-02-12


                          Table_Schedule

MembersName    ScheduleDate      ScheduleTime

Banog, Anna     2014-02-11         13:30:00

Result: 
MinimumLoginTime = 00:26:00
MaximumLogoutTime = 01:01:00


Desired Result:
MinimumLoginTime = 12:49:00
MaximumLogoutTime = 01:01:00
```

I dont know why the time "00:26:00" is there, but since it was the data from the database then it must be resolved. The only thing which is clear here is that i need to compare the time(array) from table_logs with table_schedule and find the closest scheduleTime to loginTime. So far here's my code:

```
 Dim mylist2 As New List(Of List(Of String))
 Dim mylist1 As New List(Of List(Of String))

 For i As Integer = 0 To x - 1

 query = "Select Count(*), agentName, loginDate, Min(loginTime) as loginTime, Max(logoutDate) as logoutDate FROM tbl_login WHERE agentName='" & mylist(i)(1).ToString & "' AND loginDate ='" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "'"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, SQLConnection)
            count = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            If count >= 1 Then
                Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While reader.Read()
                        Dim ls As New List(Of String)
                        agentName = reader.GetString(1)
                        Dim LoginDates As Date = reader.GetString(2)
                        loginDate = LoginDates.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        Dim timeIn As Date = reader.GetString(3)
                        actualLoginTime = timeIn.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
                        Dim logoutDate As Date = reader.GetString(4)
                        actualLogoutDate = logoutDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        ls.Add(agentName)
                        ls.Add(loginDate)
                        ls.Add(actualLoginTime)
                        ls.Add(actualLogoutDate)
                        mylist1.Add(ls)
                    End While
                    reader.Close()
                End Using
            Else
                Dim ls As New List(Of String)
                agentName = "Absent"
                loginDate = "Absent"
                ls.Add(agentName)
                ls.Add(loginDate)
                ls.Add("00:00:00")
                ls.Add("Absent")
                mylist1.Add(ls)
            End If

            If mylist(i)(1).ToString() = "Absent " Then
                Dim ls As New List(Of String)
                ls.Add("00:00:00")
                mylist2.Add(ls)
            Else
                query = "Select Count(*), Max(logoutTime) as logoutTime FROM tbl_login WHERE agentName='" & mylist1(i)(0).ToString() & "' AND logoutDate ='" & mylist1(i)(3).ToString() & "' AND loginDate = '" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "'"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, SQLConnection)
                count = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                If count >= 1 Then
                    Using readers As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        While readers.Read()
                            Dim ls As New List(Of String)
                            Dim timeOut As Date = readers.GetString(1)
                            actualLogoutTime = timeOut.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
                            ls.Add(actualLogoutTime)
                            mylist2.Add(ls)
                        End While
                    End Using
                Else
                    Dim ls As New List(Of String)
                    ls.Add("00:00:00")
                    mylist2.Add(ls)
                End If
            End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that 12:49 is 12:49 PM just before 1 in the afternoon (PM) and 00:49 is just before 1 in the morning (AM.) You may just have a data entry problem.

Comment: Where did 00:49 came from? I only have 00:26, 12:49 and 13:16 in the sample data's.